# Why does parsing a string with a minus in it fail?

Tags: haskell, parsec

Why does this fail?

```
data Value = Num Integer
           | Str String

let numberOrString = (liftM Num (try int) <|> liftM Str (many1 (noneOf " "))
parse (numberOrString >> space)  "" "123-4 "
```

The `>> space` is required. Else the parser would stop after `123`

Expected result:

```
parse numberOrString "" "1234"
-> Num 1234

parse numberOrString "" "12-34"
-> Str "12-34"
```

Result:

```
parse numberOrString "" "1234-34 "
-> Left (line 1, column 5):
   unexpected "-"
   expecting digit or space
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not give the definitions for the `int` parser combinator, but let's assume that it essentially expects one or more digits, optionally with a "-" in front (but only in front!). Now let's walk through your `numberOrString` parser.

It parses an integer literal, or failing that, a string of non space characters. On your example string, the first branch of your parser will succeed, because it sees a string of digits. It will stop right before the "-" character, because that is not a digit. Now, `numberOrString >> space` will fail becauseafter a number, we are expecting the next character to be a space, which "-" is not.

You have essentially applied your parser to a string of *two* integer literals, one positive and one negative (or two positive literals separated by a "-", depending on your grammar). This is also the reason why applying the `numberOfString` parser alone only consumes "1234", because that is the maximal integer literal that it can parse.

**Edit:** what I'm guessing you want is for `try int` to fail if there are any non-digit characters in a string of mostly digits. Again, this really depends on your definition of `int`, but it's probably defined as a parser that succeeds on any string of at least one digit that is not followed by an alphabetic character. Usual definitions of `int` will succeed on strings of digits followed by non alphanumber characters, such as "-", even without any intervening space character, because that makes the spaces between two integer literals and an infix operator optional. Also, it allows you to successfully parse "123)", without having to write "123 )".

Comment: (The fact that the string is 2 integer literals is irrelevant, it fails in exactly the same way with `"1234a34"`.)

Comment: Not exactly a solution but all i gave was a question why it didn't worked. At it got me on the right track. Thanks!